# Converting a massive JSON file to CSV

Tags: sql, json, csv

I have a JSON file which is 48MB (collection of tweets I data mined). I need to convert the JSON file to CSV so I can import it into a SQL database and cleanse it.

I've tried every JSON to CSV converter but they all come back with the same result of "file exceeds limits" / the file is too large. Is there a good method of converting such a massive JSON file to CSV within a short period of time?

Thank you!

Comment: @msanford says JSON to CSV.

Comment: @CodyG. So it does...

Comment: You could try to see if Excel Power Query works for your conversion, if you're looking for a non-programming based solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 48mb json file is pretty small. You should be able to load the data into memory using something like this

```
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

Dependending on how you wrote to the json file, data may be a list, which contains many dictionaries. Try running:

```
type(data)
```

If the type is a list, then iterate over each element and inspect it. For instance:

```
for row in data:
    print(type(row))
    # print(row.keys())
```

If row is a dict instance, then inspect the keys and within the loop, start building up what each row of the CSV should contain, then you can either use pandas, the csv module or just open a file and write line by line with commas yourself.

So maybe something like:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)


with open('some_file.txt', 'w') as f:

    for row in data:
        user = row['username']
        text = row['tweet_text']
        created = row['timestamp']
        joined = ",".join([user, text, created])
        f.write(joined)
```

You may still run into issues with unicode characters, commas within your data, etc...but this is a general guide.

Comment: Looks like a good answer, but OP doesn't specify any programming language... ;(